# Вызов 2 метода PostMapping на один адрес

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

У меня есть 2 формы с методами POST в одном html-файле.

Как я могу в Controller обрабатывать запрос первой формы когда нужно и обрабатывать запрос второй формы когда нужно?

То есть когда я нажимаю на button первой формы, я хочу вызывать метод (например `"Form1"`), а когда нажимаю на button второй формы, я хочу вызвать метод `"Form2"`.

```xml
<form th:action="@{/finish_registration}" th:object="${newUser}" method="post">
           ...
        <form th:action="@{/finish_registration}" th:object="${newUser}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div style="padding-top: 1rem;">
                <label for="file-upload" class="btn btn-sm main_btn">
                    Upload Image
                </label>
                <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-sm main_btn"/>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-sm-7"/>
            </div>
        </form>
         ...
        <button type="submit" value="Registration" name="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-sm-7"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Нельзя формы делать вложенными.  Каждая форма маппится на метод контроллера с помощью аннотации @RequestMapping

Comment: @RomanC, хорошо, я объеденил 2 формы и тепереь у меня есть одна форма, но 2 кнопки submit.
Есть ли способ при нажатии одной кнопки вызывать один метод, а при нажатии второй кнопки вызывать другой метод?

Comment: Есть и не один, я насчитал четыре способа.

Comment: @RomanC а можете поделиться этими способами ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак одна форма может маппиться на один метод в контроллере, но нажатие кнопки может поменять назначение формы. Так, например

```xml
<button value="Registration 1" onclick="form.action='/finish_registration/Registration1;form.submit()">
<button value="Registration 2" onclick="form.action='/finish_registration/Registration2;form.submit()">
```

Соответственно на разные методы ставить соответствующую аннотацию.

```
@RequestMapping("/finish_registration/Registration1")
@RequestMapping("/finish_registration/Registration2")
```

Comment: Спаcибо большое, вы очень помогли :)